# Magento 1.9 : Partial Update stock quantity with dataflow

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, dataflow

The question is simple.

Using "Import Dataflow" to update stock quantity, can i use a csv file where are presents only the product I want to update?

I mean I have 300 products in my store.

If I want to update stock quantity only of 50 of them, can I use a csv with that 50 products information? Or I have anyway use a 300 lines file?

I can't experiment this cause the site in running, so if I loose all the products it will be a mess for me.

Thank u for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Using the "Import Dataflow" you can update any set of SKUs and their quantities. So, you'll have two columns, one for SKU and the other for qty, and just list them in separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

IN import dataflow it only update those product whose sku are define in csv.

Before doing that you can took the backup of database.